# Merge two sorted array,. My output is not coming out correctly. Kindly help find the issue

Tags: arrays, c, merge

I am entering input but the output is not coming out as expected. See the below attached to see the problem. Where should I modify my code? After entering the elements output is coming out as like it is storing a garbage value and not the sorted elements provided.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("\nProgram to merge two arrays in ascending order\n");
    printf("************************************************************");
    int n,m;
    printf("\nEnter size of 1st array: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\nEnter size of 2nd array: ");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    
    int a[n], b[m],c[m+n], i=0, j=0, k=0;

    printf("Enter elements in ascending order only.\n");
    printf("Enter elements of 1st array.\n ");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter element %d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }

    printf("Enter elements of 2nd array.\n ");
    for(j=0; j<m; j++)
    {
        printf("Enter element %d: ",j+1);
        scanf("%d",&b[j]);
    }

    while(i<n && j<m)
    {
        if(a[i]<b[j])
        {
                c[k] = a[i];
                k++;
                i++;
        }
        else
        {
                c[k] = b[j];
                k++;
                j++;
        }
    }
    while(i<n)
        c[k++] = a[i++];

    while(j<m)
        c[k++] = b[j++];

    //Now printing array 3rd
    for(i=0; i<m+n; i++){
        printf("%d ",c[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: This is the error that I m facing]

Comment: C and C ++ are different languages. Pick one.

Answer (score 1):

After taking input you need to set i and j back to zero like:

```
i = 0;
j = 0;
while(i<n && j<m)
```